# Find white space in string

Tags: php, string

I have the following string. I need to find the position of the last white space.

I have tried the following code:

```
for ($i = 410; $i < 420; $i++) {
            if ($body[$i] == ' ') {
                $lastCharacter = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

But it does not return the correct white space position. It return a position in middle of a word.

> Dans cette septième étape, les coureurs vont relier Montpellier et
>   Albi, passant au milieu des vignes de l'arrière-pays pour faire la
>   jonction entre les Alpes et les Pyrénées, traversant des paysages qui
>   font toute la saveur du Tour. Dernière étape un peu plate avant un
>   week-end placé sous le signe de la montagne. Des ascensions de col, la
>   foule amassée sur les côtés, souffrant avec leu...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$lastSpace = strrpos($string," ");
```

Doc: [strrpos](https://www.php.net/strrpos)

Comment: That code will find the position of a _space_ but miss other white space, like the _tab_ or _new line_ characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strrpos` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

`echo $pos = strrpos($mystring, " ");`